# How do I show and hide a component in my header based on the router history in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I would like to show and hide a button in my navigation at the top of the web application based on what router path is currently loaded in my vue application. I have a component called HeaderComponent that has my top level navigation.

I've not found a good way to bind to the changes in the `$router.options.history.location` provided by vue.

I'd like to do something like this.

```
<form class="xs:invisible sm:invisible md:visible" v-show="$router.options.history.location != '/main'">
     <button>click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a computed property which would bind to the routers location. If that fails, put $route inside of the watch object of your navigation component.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to `$route.path` instead:

```html
<form v-show="$route.path !== '/main'">
```

There are [other properties](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) too you can use. If you have named routes then a better approach that doesn't rely on the path is:

```html
<form v-show="$route.name !== 'main'">
```

If you have nested routes then you might need to do instead:

```html
<form v-show="!$route.matched.some(r => r.name === 'main')">
```

I *think* this API is unchanged from Vue Router version 3 (i.e. Vue 2).

Comment: I ended up using the named route option. Thanks.